# bash while loop to delete a line from a file

Tags: regex, bash, while-loop

I have a dataset that I call 'chuck' and I need to get rid of one recurring line
and I don't want to use sed or grep -v to a tmp file. I wwant to
use a while loop, and pattern recognition.

```
D,642,0642,UBF,FOO,,M,,L,L,HPQ,9926,11080,
D,642,0642,UBF,FOO,,M,,S,S,IBM,11062,5122,
D,642,0642,UBF,FOO,,M,,S,S,INTC,35216,39833,
D,642,0642,UBF,FOO,,M,,S,S,FARFERNUGEN,213,213,
D,642,0642,UBF,FOO,,M,,L,L,JNJ,15607,12714,
D,642,0642,UBF,FOO,,M,,L,L,JPM,51225,40013,
```

SO I am catting out the file I call 'chuck' and I am trying to run this through a while loop and I am trying
to get each string though the while loop except the string that
I am trying to get out. What am I doing wrong here.  Because the output is exactly the same.

```
#!/bin/bash
pattern="D,642,0642,UBF,FOO,,M,,S,S,Farfegnugen,213,213,"
cat /tmp/chuck | while read line
do
   [[ ! $s =~ "$pattern" ]] && echo $line
done
```

Comment: Neither `$s` nor `$string` have a value in that script.

Comment: And there a dangling `i` in your `$pattern`

Comment: If that trailing `i` was intended to be a flag for "case insensitive" that isn't going to work. That can't be specified that way (and that attempt doesn't end up the way you would think it would).

Comment: That edit fixed `$string` but not `$s`.

Comment: Unless you give some reasons for "I don't want to use sed or grep -v", I'll just think "what a weirdo" and close the window. :p

Comment: And for exact match use `==` instead of `=~`

Comment: @Amadam  - or anyone else, How would you do it using sed or grep -v?

Answer (score 2):

The testing line should be:

```
[[ $line =~ $pattern ]] || echo "$line"
```

You were using `$s` in the test, which doesn't exist.

Using deMorgan's Law, you can remove the `!` from the test and change the boolean operator to `||` to get the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach has a number of problems, not least of which is performance.  I would expect the equivalent `sed -i` script to run a lot faster than a shell loop.

But if you insist on using the shell, you should:

- avoid Useless Use of `cat`;
- be aware that `read` by default will mangle some inputs (use `read -r`);
- still, depending on your `IFS`, `read` is brittle;
- quote all your variables, unless you specifically require the shell to tokenize the string on whitespace and perform wildcard expansion on the tokens;
- and, obviously, if you want to test the variable `$line`, don't test `$s`

With these things taken into account, we obtain

```
#!/bin/bash
pattern="D,642,0642,UBF,FOO,,M,,S,S,DUMOSGI,213,213,"
IFS='
'
while read -r line; do
   [[ ! "$line" =~ $pattern ]] && echo "$line"
done </tmp/chuck
```

If the pattern is static, using regex pattern matching is an unnecessary performance hit.